# HTML/CSS: Adjust elements based on screen dimension without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I have the following default html 2-column scheme:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="left"> sidebar stuff</div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="topbar">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                </ul>            
                <div id="iconmenu">
                    <button>a</button>
                    <button>b</button>
                    <button>c</button>
                    <button>d</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div style="border: 1px solid black; height:400px">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/K9K8b/1/

I want to let the iconbar stay at the position on the right (when decreasing window size) without using JavaScript. Is there a way to do this, probably by using a kind of placeholder and the min/max-width attribute?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute like in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/K9K8b/2/

```
#iconmenu {
    padding-right: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

It should get you in the right direction at least...

Comment: Hmmm ... menu doesn't move on resizing in your fiddle.